# Identifying the story where the girl doesn't know that she's actually a robot until the very end

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

### The plot

It is an apocalyptic period, the world is overrun by robots, and the girl (female main protagonist, but I forgot her name) is struggling to survive. She has the help of a robot that helps bring her food that was with her before the apocalypse.

You can put your consciousness inside the robot in the form of a disk, and 1 robot can't hold more than one consciousness.

The robots don't have emotions but they try to live like humans (doing the everyday things humans did) in order to feel emotions or understand them. The robots have weapons blocking her path to wherever she wants to go.

Later she ends up getting captured by the robots and is forced to work alongside others. Later the others find out her identity, and because she's good with robots because of her father she's sent to treat the leader of all the robots which actually turns out to be human. However, the person has a broken consciousness or a bad link. As she pretends to be fixing the leader (the main villain) instead of fixing him she implants a different disk in his body that helps solve the apocalypse or crisis.

The girl's dad used to be the greatest robot maker of her time. And at one point the girl got really sick, however she thought she got better. But it turns out she died and actually her consciousness was actually transferred to the robot. She's the only robot capable of feeling pain and emotions.

She doesn't know that, though, and as the novel ends her robot companion puts her hand in the fire saying "stop thinking about it and you won't feel the pain anymore". At a point the pain gets scorching hot, however slowly it dies away and you can see metal behind the burnt skin, making her realise that she's actually a robot.

Comment: This is tagged with "books" and "novels", but in the last paragraph you say "as the movie ends".  Which is this, book or movie?  Also, would be really good to have a date range at least for when you saw or read this.

Comment: If it was a movie, what era would it be from?  Was it a minimal, low-budget movie, did it have fancy practical effects, or was it CGI?  If it was a book, when did you read it, what did the cover look like, how thick was it...?

Comment: Part of this sounds like Princess Anevka from [Girl Genius](https://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20060911#.YdUxnuCIadM), but it's different enough that it's probably just a different story with similar ideas.

Answer (score 2):

### Possibly [The Creation of the Humanoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Creation_of_the_Humanoids), a movie from 1962

From the Wikipedia page:

> Scientist Dr. Raven (Doolittle) has developed a technique called a "thalamic transplant", which transfers the memories and personality of a recently deceased human into a robotic replica of that person. The human-humanoid hybrids that result awake from the process unaware of their own transformation, although their human personalities are shut off between 4 and 5 A.M., when they report back to the humanoids at the robot temple. As Dr. Raven describes the operation, "We draw off everything that makes a man peculiar to himself. His learning, his memory: these, inter-reacting, constitute his personality, his philosophy, capability and attitude. The human brain is merely the vault in which the man is stored." With the help of Dr. Raven, the humanoids are secretly replacing humans who recently died with these replicas.
>
> One of the leaders of the Order of Flesh and Blood, Captain Kenneth Cragis (Megowan), meets Maxine, and although she is opposed to the Order they both fall in love. In the end they discover that they, too, are advanced humanoid replicas with the minds of deceased persons. Ironically, the "real" Maxine had died in a bomb attack which the Order intended to harm only robots. Dr. Raven, a once-human replica himself, explains to Cragis and Maxine that not only are they practically immortal in their new forms they can also be the first humanoids upgraded to the highest possible level: after a minor alteration, they will be able to procreate.

Comment: [You can watch the film here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2wczk3). The ending doesn't match the description in the question.

Comment: @JohnRennie doesn't really surprise me, there was a lot that didn't line up in the description. But ever some a story ID question that described the MCs as wizards when they were in fact djinn I'll post any story with enough points in common even if the remaining points directly contradicte the story. You never know what's been misremembered.

Answer (score 2):

It’s ***[Frost](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/28599500)*** (2016) by M.P. Kozlowsky.

> Sixteen-year-old Frost understands why she’s spent her entire life in an abandoned apartment building. The ruined streets below are hunting grounds for rogue robots and Eaters.
>
> She understands why she’s never met a human besides her father. She even understands why he forbids her to look for medicine for her dying pet. But the thing is, it’s not her real father giving the orders…
>
> It’s his memories.
>
> Before he died, Frost’s father uploaded his consciousness into their robot servant. But the technology malfunctioned, and now her father fades in and out. So when Frost learns that there might be medicine on the other side of the ravaged city, she embarks on a dangerous journey to save the one living creature she loves.
>
> With only a robot as a companion, Frost must face terrors of all sorts, from outrunning the vicious Eaters…to talking to the first boy she’s ever set eyes on. But can a girl who’s only seen the world through books and dusty windows survive on her own? Or will her first journey from home be her last?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Ca you explain how this matches the description provided in the question?