# Book involving the murder trial of a scientist who uploaded his daughter's mind to a computer

Tags: story-identification, books, mind-uploading

I read it in the early 80's. But not necessarily published then. A slim hardback with a black and white cover and just the title which was something like "The Curious Case of" + girl's name.

The gist of the story was a scientist had a daughter with a fatal disease. He decided to upload his daughter's consciousness to a computer while she was still cogent but also quite young. The majority of the book was the trial where he argued he was not guilty of murder because her consciousness was still alive.
A scene that sticks with me is when the woman journalist is interviewing the scientist he tries to make a point by having her smash a whimpering robot with a hammer.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=curious+case&C=AND&USE_2=title_title&O_2=exact&TERM_2=&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title - One of these, perhaps

Comment: I'm not certain "Curious" is in the title. Could be the Fantastic Case or Strange Case any thing like that Peculiar. I can't remember .. but thank you.

Comment: Titles matching ["case"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=case&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title); I don't see anything likely here either.

Comment: Reminded me of [this recent post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/259004/identifying-the-story-where-the-girl-doesnt-know-that-shes-actually-a-robot-un) but probably not the same story now that I compare them.